# Download a copy of the module definitions from my drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a simple drupal website already running. I am new to drupal.

How can I download a version of the modules running in the drupal website server? I have my admin access right. I am able to add content, views, etc. But I want to download the entire set of modules , like I had before deploying the website. I mean I want the 'modules' folder downloaded from my drupal website to my local file system, with all my custom setting codings (in php and angular js).  Is there any possibility for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have FTP or SSH access to the server if you want to download the module files.  Once you have access, you can download the entire `/sites/all/modules/` folder.